# Can you make a text input that allows you to type text, but doesn't allow you to delete text?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking at [How to prevent user from deleting text in a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266398/how-to-prevent-user-from-deleting-text-in-a-text-box?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and other similar questions, but I can't find how to do this.

How do you 'be able to write text', but 'not be able to delete text'. Is it possible to for example, not do anything when Backspace or Delete is pressed?

I haven't got a lead on this question yet, so I don't really have any code to show in a demo.

Just to clarify:

I'm trying to make a `<input type='text'/>`, which allows you to type in it, but not delete text inside. Is it possible? I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I haven't found a answer to this question yet.

If it is 'possible', then I need it to be in pure Javascript. I don't really like other things other then pure javascript, css and html.

EDIT:

Thanks to the commentors, I have a few things to keep note of now, such as the onChange event. I'll be trying to be doing this myself at the same time...

Thanks @Isacc for answering half of my question. I'll go and accept the answer now. I'm pretty sure I can work out the rest by myself now. All I needed was just some code to start off with.

@ARN, that just fixed most of the rest of the question! Thank you! :D

@Kavian_K, I really appreciate you trying to help! :)

And @user3210641, thanks for completing the full question! :)

@Arun Bhat, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for submitting a answer!

Comment: onkeyChange or onChangeText method, try to detect the keystroke, and prevent from doing anything

Comment: Why would you want this? It's clearly possible, but what purpose does an input field server that you can't use when you mistype?

Comment: Is it possible or not? Hopefully someone can help with this. I'm sorry I don't have any source code because I have no idea at all how to do so. Thanks @Isaac for the help by the way. In theory, is it possible though Luca?

Comment: @Luca: There are so many creative or custom use cases around the world which makes this world interesting. It's kinda pointless to ask for `purpose` imho

Comment: Hey! What's that downvote for? I made sure that this question wasn't asked before, it isn't a duplicate and yeah... :( rip my rep. Still trying to get to 50 rep to be able to comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the previous answer should be marked as correct as you can change the content of the input field by pasting new text or by highlighting some part of the text and typing.

Here is a complete solution:

```js
let content = '';

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const value = this.value;
  
  if (this.value.length > content.length && value.indexOf(content) === 0) {
    content = value;
    return;
  }
  
  this.value = content;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Explanation: Everytime the input value changes it checks whether the updated input value is longer (characters have been added) than the previous one and if it contains all characters from the previous one - if so it adds new characters and updates content variable, otherwise is sets the value of input to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for completing the full question! :D

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
};
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
```

Do have a look at above code, it detect the key and cancel the action by returning false `onkeydown`

Comment: Thanks! :D That's one half of this done. Now i have to figure out how to disable the other ways

Comment: @Lorddirt: Do mark it as answer if it answered your question, as reference for other developer facing similar issues, thanks

Comment: 10 minute delay after asking question to be able to accept answers. I'll accept it in 10 minutes. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: To avoid cutting text you can add an onchange event and if the string is shorter than the previous value, you can reset its value to the previous one

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thank you so much! +1uv

Comment: I expect that this will be similar for the opposite? ie) if every key except 8 and 46 is pressed, return false to disable typing but enable deleting?

Comment: @Lorddirt,  don't be afraid to change the code, always try it out yourself

Comment: Great! :D Thank you for helping so much with this question! I know it's strange, but I actually need the strange code xD.

Answer (score 1):

The below function prevent user from `delete`, `cut` and `paste` the input box value:

```js
$( '#txt' ).on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;

  if ( key == 8 || key == 46 ) e.preventDefault();
} ).on( 'cut paste', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault()
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="txt" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
```

Comment: Thank you! Wanted pure javascript, but I really appreciate you trying to help! +1 up vote

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work.

```
function noBackSpace()
{
if(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)
{
    alert("No Back Space");
    return false;
}
}

<input type="text" name="txt" value="" onkeydown="return noBackSpace()">
```

Comment: Hi new user! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering this question! :D